# I have Call Of Duty World at War on CD, but no CD player anymore. Is there a legal way to obtain a virtual copy of it?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war

I bought a long time ago Call of Duty World at War.

However, I do not have a CD player anymore. Is there a way to obtain it (without buying a second time !) on a game seller platform like Steam ?

Comment: I don't have a copy so can't check but do you have a serial key with the game and have you tried entering it into Steam or Battle.net?

Comment: @TheBetpet Tried right now. The key is not considered valid by steam and World at War is not propsoed by battle.net :(

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution would be to just purchase an external cd/dvd drive. They're pretty cheap and usually just plug in a USB port.

Another option is to use a computer that does have a cd drive and create an iso image of your disk. You can then use that image on your own computer.
However, it depends on your country and the game publisher if this is allowed. I believe that for example in the US you are allowed to make backup copies of software that you own, but this is not the case in UK.
So make sure to check this first before considering this.